# Accessing same HashMap from MainGUI (jDialog) into another jDialog class

Tags: java, user-interface, jdialog

Main GUI(jDialog) - creates an instance of a class which has a HashMap (Lets call this HashMapClass) within this GUI. Able to access the methods to return the HashMap inside this class.

Secondary GUI(jDialog) - Wanting to access the same instance of the class which has the HashMap, not create a new instance inside this jDialog. (want to access the same HashMap with the same data inside)

This is what i've tried so far. This is a button from the Main GUI to open up the Secondary GUI.

Main GUI

```
private HashMapClass hashMapClassNo;

jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        SecondaryGUI sec = new SecondaryGUI(null);
        sec.setModal(true);
        sec.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        sec.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ActionListener init(HashMapClass hashMapClass) {
         hashMapClass = hashMapClassNo;
         return this;
    }

}.init(hashMapClassNo));
```

This compiles, but I still cannot access the methods using external method calls, or the HashMaps inside the SecondaryGUI.

How do i access the methods from one jDialog, into another?

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a new method to an anonymous inner class, and that will never work. I'm not even sure what you're trying to achieve with the `init()` method. Myself, if I want another class to have *direct* access to an object, I'd pass that object into the other class via a constructor parameter or a setter method.

e.g.,

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        SecondaryGUI sec = new SecondaryGUI(hashMapClassNo); // pass it in
        sec.setModal(true);
        sec.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        sec.setVisible(true);
    }
};
```

A better solution is to use an MVC design pattern, but that will require more up-front work on your part, but is worth it if this is a large complex program and thus you absolutely need to create highly cohesive low-coupling testable classes.

Comment: Tried doing this, and it made me change loads of stuff in the SecondaryGUI, changing constructors and stuff, still got NullPointerException error.

Comment: @james11: then your concept was correct, but your implementation was incorrect. Please feel free to show that code and that error if you need help with it. Not sure but you may need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.